# react-router v4 add query parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4 for a React app.

In a form, I want to add query parameters on the onSubmit action

My code looks like this:

```
class FiltroCuentasCorrientes extends Component {
 ...//Other stuff.

 onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const { someVariable, otherVariable } = this.state;
   //Here I should add the variables to the query param.
 }

 render() {
  <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.onSubmit(e)}>
    ...
  </Form>
  }
}
```

I don't know what the recommended approach is.

Should I have a variable in local state like `shouldAddParam` and render a `<Redirect />` with my params?

Or use the `router` context and the `navigateTo` method?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to compose the `action` attribute of the `form` element during the `render()`, if that is possible. This way there's no need to prevent default.

However, if you want to "programatically redirect" using React router, then yes, you should use

```
this.context.router.push(path)
```

... as you can see in [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/12-navigating).